# How to get value from web_page(url_launcher)

Tags: flutter, webview, token

[image]

I want to log in with the web page implemented by the backend. However, URL_LAUNCHER or WEBVIEW is required to log in. I want to receive a message after completing social login, but I don't know how to do it. Thank you.

[image]

```
Future<void> signIn() async {
  String _url = "https://kauth.kakao.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=7f8c9995a36f55554348032c83b16b96&redirect_uri=ss";
  if(await launchUrl(Uri.parse(_url)));
```

Comment: Use inappwebview and evaluvate javascript method to get the data.

Comment: You can use dependency called web scraper
https://pub.dev/packages/web_scraper

Answer (score 0):

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_web_auth#web-auth-for-flutter
use webauth lib~

```
import 'package:flutter_web_auth/flutter_web_auth.dart';

// Present the dialog to the user
final result = await FlutterWebAuth.authenticate(url: "https://my-custom-app.com/connect", callbackUrlScheme: "my-custom-app");

// Extract token from resulting url
final token = Uri.parse(result).queryParameters['token']
```